# Get Top ViewController TabsWithNavigationControllerPresenter MVVMCross

Tags: ios, mvvmcross

Here is my scenario :

I need to access "TopViewController" in iOS using MVVMCross. I want to show a Pop-up view on TopViewController where I'm using "TabsWithNavigationControllerPresenter" too.

I want something generic where I could show a popup based on ViewModel's command having different parameters for pop-up view.

Can someone help me with this scenario?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like https://github.com/brianchance/MvvmCross-UserInteraction ?

If it's not exactly what you are looking, you could either:

1. modify the code yourself
2. create your own service to show the popup you need

In MvvmCross you can use I guess

```
(Mvx.Resolve<IMvxTouchViewPresenter>() as MvxTouchViewPresenter).MasterNavigationController.TopViewController
```

See
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/Presenters/MvxTouchViewPresenter.cs#L151